# Scalability of python's BaseHTTPHandler?

Tags: python, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I am using python's standard API (BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHander) as a backend for handling users' HTTP requests. Now, assuming on an average, the number of users on my website will be around 150, will it be safe to stick with this python's API?

Comment: Concurrent users; All logged in at once? Are you running only one instance of the server?

Comment: yeah! one instance of the server and all logged in at once! or should I use multithreaded server instead?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt. At least use a proper web server for static assets like Apache or Nginx. Plenty of other Python frameworks, too. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks